# Замена символов через регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Небольшие знания о регулярках у меня есть. Мне надо почитать, как использовать в java регулярные выражения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно почитать. 
И второй вопрос: как в java составить регулярное выражение для замены всех символов `//` и `\\` на `/`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Шаблон примерно такой:

```
Pattern pattern  = Pattern.compile("Здесь будет регулярное выражение");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("строка для разбора");
String result = matcher.replaceAll("/"); // строка с результатом (замена всего найденного на "/")
```

Ну, а дальше тренируйтесь составлять regExp =)

Answer (score 4):

Почитать: [информация из первых уст](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Не знаю как составить регулярное выражение для замены, но если все ваши данные в java хранятся в переменной типа String вы можете gпопробовать воспользоваться её методом replace().

Answer (score 3):

Добрый день!

Если вы хотите разобраться с регулярными выражениями, то посоветовал бы выучить их синтаксис по табличкам хэлпа Action Script 3.0, [help](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fdb.html) - там всё понятно описано, я по ним учил, они такие же как в Java. А потом тонкости синтаксиса вызова этих регулярных выражений в Java довольна таки разжевано тут - [синтаксис вызова в Java](http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/regexp.html).

Удачи в учении! :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
/*     //\\//\  - неэкранированная строка    */

String text = "//\\\\//\\"; // экранированная строка

String replased = text.replaceAll("\\/\\/|\\\\", "/"); //замена
```